# Way of finding farthest two points in a list (scheme)

Tags: scheme, distance

I'm trying to write a procedure that returns the longest distance between the farthest two points in a list. My list is

```
((2 . 4) (3 . 6) (5 . 12) (-4 . 3) (8.4 . 9) (0 . -1))
```

And i've already written a distance procedure and one that returns the maximum distance between two points:

```
(define (max-distance p pt-list)
    (if (null? pt-list)
        0
        (max (distance p (car pt-list))
             (max-distance p (cdr pt-list)))))
```

Now, I just need to write something that only returns the largest value obtained by taking two of those points. What I have so far is

```
 (define (max-range pt-list)
     (if (null? pt-list)
         0
         (max (max-distance (car pt-list) (pt-list))
              (max-range (cdr pt-list)))))
```

However, when i run the test case `(display+ (max-range my-pt-list))` i get the error: The object ((0 . -1)) is not applicable, which leads me to believe that it is working up until it reaches the last point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this line in `max-range`:

```
(max-distance (car pt-list) (pt-list))
```

It should be:

```
(max-distance (car pt-list) pt-list)
```

Notice that you have to pass the list, not apply it (it's not a function). That's what the error is pointing.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've overlooked using `cdr`.  In your `max-range` function you call `max-distance` - the arguments to that call should be the `car` and `cdr` of `pt-list`.  As such:

```
(define (max-range pt-list)
  (if (null? pt-list)
      0
      (max (max-distance (car pt-list) (cdr pt-list))
           (max-range (cdr pt-list)))))
```

You use `cdr` on the second argument because there is no reason to recompute the distance for `(car pt-list)` (it will be zero and never the maximum).